# Get working directory of logged in users

Tags: command-line

`w` lists all logged in users. Is there any way to get the working directory for the logged in users?

Comment: What if I have three terminals open, each in a different working directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current working directory is a property of each process, not of users.

On Linux, you can get the current working directory of a process of id `$pid` by doing a `readlink()` on `/proc/$pid/cwd` for instance by using the `readlink`/`realpath` command or the `:a`/`:A`/`:P` glob qualifiers in `zsh`. Unless you're superuser, that only works for your own processes though (the current working directory like what other file a process is currently accessing is a potentially sensitive information).

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9467 pts/1    00:00:00 zsh
14074 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
$ readlink /proc/9467/cwd
/usr/local
$ printf '%s\n' /proc/9467/cwd(:P)
/usr/local
```

More portably, you can use `lsof`:

```
$ lsof -ap 9467 -d cwd
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
zsh     9467 chazelas  cwd    DIR  253,0     4096 786604 /usr/local
```

Then you can combine it with `-u user` instead of `-p pid` to get the cwd of all the processes running as that user:

```
sudo lsof -au user -d cwd
```

On some systems, like FreeBSD, `sudo` (to run the command with superuser privileges) is not required as access to that information is not restricted there.